# What is the best tool for migrating from ClearCase to TFS2008?

Tags: version-control, tfs, migration, clearcase, tfs-migration

We are moving from ClearCase to TFS2008. I easily found the MS migration tool but it seems to be targeted to TFS 2005. Any suggestions on other tools that could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When  you will use this migration tool, keep in mind:

- TFS early branching and ClearCase just-in-time branching [are different](http://blogs.msdn.com/tfs_migration/archive/2007/09/13/migrating-clearcase-branches-to-tfs.aspx), meaning you need a config spec (on the ClearCase side) reflecting files for a given branch (even if all files have not technically any version created on that branch). A good way to to that is to ensure the presence of a label (or better a baseline) on a coherent set of files (you want to import), label put a the imported branch.
- you should not seek to import *all* ClearCase versions of all files, but rather only the labeled one, provided you can determine that label has been put on *all* the files of a given set. This is easier with UCM, since a baseline is by definition a label put on all the files of a component.

So if that ClearCase to TFS2008 migration script does take labels/baselines and is able to determine to what branch/stream they are associated with, you are on the right path.